# UITableViewCell set Border

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios

I have a normal `UITableViewCell` with custom colors, but how can i change the border?

Currently it looks very ugly:

[image: Screenshot]

I only want a tiny little white border.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
[tableView setSeparatorColor:];
```

... i believe ...

Comment: tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor]; removes the border total.

Comment: then use `tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor greenColor];`